# What is the visual indication when Hysteria triggers?

Tags: diablo-iii

What is the visual indication in-game that the Scoundrel's "Hysteria" skill has triggered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any.  The only indication you will see is a slight DPS boost in your character sheet for a few seconds.